# Determine Winter or Summertime due to month (UTC Timezone)

Tags: arrays, bash, time

I am facing an issue with a bash script that I am writing. I am pretty new to bash scripts so I would be glad for some help or inputs.

We are running an Appliance Server. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to change the timezone of this server. So I need to work with the UTC Timezone.

Now I wanted to create script that should run automatically in our maintenance window at 8 PM. Now the problem is, that UTC does not know the difference between summer / winter time.

So I tried the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
array_time=("Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct")

ZONE=`date | cut -c 5-7`
echo $ZONE

if [[ " ${array_time[@]} " == " ${ZONE} " ]]; then
echo "SUMMERTIME CRONJOB"
else
echo "WINTERTIME CRONJOB"
fi
```

But for some reason, this is the output:

```
./test.sh
Jul
WINTERTIME CRONJOB
```

So even when the value Jul is part of the array_time variable, it goes to the else part of the if condition. I am not sure why this is happening. Anyone got an idea why? Or maybe anyone got a better idea how to solve this?

Thanks for your help

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in:

```
[[ " ${array_time[@]} " == " ${ZONE} " ]]
```

which will never be true as `${array_time[@]}` will get expanded to:

```
[[ " Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct " == " ${ZONE} " ]]
```

And `$ZONE` is never equal that string, using the following will work:

```
[[ " ${array_time[@]} " == *" ${ZONE} "* ]]
```

Also note that you can use `date +'%b'` instead of `date | cut ...`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback and for showing the reason why my script did not work. Now it is clear to me, why the == ${ZONE} did not work like that. I will test it within the afternoon. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what is your original goal, you can localy modify the timezone, for example:

```
TZ=EST date
Tue Jul  5 03:54:39 EST 2016
```

`TZ=EST date`: it is setting `TZ` environment variable to `EST`, when executing the `date` command.

You could use either regular expression or `fgrep` to search the month in an array.

Give a try to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
array_time=("Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct")

ZONE=$(date "+%b")

if [[ "${array_time[@]}" =~ "${ZONE}" ]] ; then
  printf "SUMMERTIME CRONJOB\n"
else
  printf "WINTERTIME CRONJOB\n"
fi
```

You could also use a `for` loop.

Prefer using `$(...)` to execute command.

It is encouraged to use `printf` instead of `echo`:

- see the answer from Stéphane Chazelas to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)
- see [echo utility from the The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html#tag_20_37_18)

### ----

First answer for history:

```
#!/bin/bash
array_time=("Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct")

ZONE=$(date "+%b")

if printf "%s\n" ${array_time[@]} | fgrep -q "${ZONE}" ; then
  printf "SUMMERTIME CRONJOB\n"
else
  printf "WINTERTIME CRONJOB\n"
fi
```

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for your answer. I just tested it and this is working perfectly. Thank you very much for your fast answer

Comment: Thanks for your second answer, will be testing this one in the afternoon. Also thank you for your explanation regarding printf / echo. I am still used to echo, so I will have to change this